# How to create decoration view in collection view?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create decoration view in my `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. I use this code:

```
func createListTableSection(using section: Section) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
    let layoutItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    layoutItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8)
        
    let layoutGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.93), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5))
        
    let layoutGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: layoutGroupSize, subitems: [layoutItem])

    let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)
        
    layoutSection.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
        
    layoutSection.decorationItems = [NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: RoundedBackgroundView.reuseIdentifier)]
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: layoutSection)
    layout.register(RoundedBackgroundView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: RoundedBackgroundView.reuseIdentifier)

    return layoutSection
}
```

RoundBackgroundView

```
class RoundedBackgroundView: UICollectionReusableView {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "RoundedBackgroundView"

    private var insetView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemFill
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        return view
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(insetView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            insetView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: insetView.trailingAnchor, constant: 15),
            insetView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            insetView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Thread 1: "could not dequeue a decoration view of kind:
> RoundedBackgroundView - must register as a class or nib or connect a
> prototype in a storyboard"

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the view isn't registered properly or there's a mismatch between names and names to dequeue the view.

`createListTableSection(using:)` is registered but that's wrong. This is for creating a `NSCollectionLayoutSection`, not the layout of the `UICollectionView`.

Registration should be in the place where you create your `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. That's where you normally do things: where you initialize your collection view or in your view controller's viewDidLoad.

Ex:

```
// Assuming your collection view is created something like this:
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
    // Here, you should call your createListTableSection function
    return self.createListTableSection(using: someSection)
}
layout.register(RoundedBackgroundView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: RoundedBackgroundView.reuseIdentifier)
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)

// Then, you set the collectionView to your controller's view
self.view = collectionView
```

If you're still getting an error check that your reuse identifier is correct.

Comment: Remember identifiers are case sensitive.

Comment: It is works. But I can't see decoration view

Comment: To see the decoration view, you also need to implement layoutAttributesForDecorationView method in your layout.

Comment: I can answer that question as well but you'd have to add another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76820719/how-to-create-a-decoration-view

Comment: Answered. Check link.