# How to create a decoration view?

Tags: ios

I want to create decoration view in my `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. I use this code:

```
func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
        let section = self.sections[sectionIndex]

        switch section.type {
        case "mediumTable":
            return self.createMediumTableSection(using: section)
        case "smallTable":
            return self.createSmallTableSection(using: section)
        case "listTable":
            return self.createListTableSection(using: section)
        default:
            return self.createFeaturedSection(using: section)
        }
    }
    
    layout.register(RoundedBackgroundView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: RoundedBackgroundView.reuseIdentifier)
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.view = collectionView
    
    let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    config.interSectionSpacing = 20
    layout.configuration = config
    return layout
}
```

RoundBackgroundView

```
class RoundedBackgroundView: UICollectionReusableView {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "RoundedBackgroundView"

    private var insetView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemFill
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        return view
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(insetView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            insetView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: insetView.trailingAnchor, constant: 15),
            insetView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            insetView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

But I can't see the background

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, no worries! So, the issue you're running into is that your decoration view (the one with the rounded corners) isn't showing up. To fix this, we need to tell each section to use this view as a background decoration.

Now, let's go over the changes step by step:

We need to create an instance of `NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem` and pass in the `elementKind` of the decoration view. This creates a new decoration item that we can then attach to our section.

Then, we set this newly created decoration item to the decorationItems property of our `layoutSection`. This way, the section knows it should use our decoration view as a background.

Finally, make sure you are setting a color that stands out for your `insetView` inside the `RoundedBackgroundView`. If it's the same as the collection view's background, your decoration view will blend right in and be invisible!

So, let's put this into code. I'll use your `createFeaturedSection(using:)` as an example:

```
func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
        let section = self.sections[sectionIndex]

        switch section.type {
        case "mediumTable":
            return self.createSection(using: section, type: "mediumTable")
        case "smallTable":
            return self.createSection(using: section, type: "smallTable")
        case "listTable":
            return self.createSection(using: section, type: "listTable")
        default:
            return self.createSection(using: section, type: "featured")
        }
    }

    layout.register(RoundedBackgroundView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: RoundedBackgroundView.reuseIdentifier)
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.view = collectionView

    let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    config.interSectionSpacing = 20
    layout.configuration = config
    return layout
}

func createSection(using section: Section, type: String) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    // create items, groups, etc. here based on your type
    // I'm leaving the creation of items and groups to you as this will depend on your needs

    let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: layoutGroup)

    let decorationItem = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: RoundedBackgroundView.reuseIdentifier)
    decorationItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
    
    layoutSection.decorationItems = [decorationItem]

    return layoutSection
}

class RoundedBackgroundView: UICollectionReusableView {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "RoundedBackgroundView"

    private var insetView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemFill
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        return view
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        addSubview(insetView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            insetView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: insetView.trailingAnchor, constant: 15),
            insetView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            insetView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This code now takes care of creating and registering the decoration views with the layout. In `createSection(using:type:)`, we set the decorationItems for the `layoutSection`. The decoration view is set to be an instance of `RoundedBackgroundView`, and it's created with some insets for spacing.

Remember to adjust the `createSection(using:type:)` function to handle the creation of the layout items and groups as needed for each type of section.

Now, your collection view should display the decoration view as a background for the items in your sections.